# Customizing only selected radio button, if button selection changes, previously selected button returns to original

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used radio buttons to allow for only 1 button being selected
That worked
I customised the original look
I managed to customise the selected button
But when I change the selection, the first button still keeps the selected colors along with the new selection
I can't seem to only allow one to be the selected colors

```
<fieldset class="numbers-container">
          <div class="number">
            <input type="radio" id="no1" name="numbers" value="1" />
            <label for="no1">1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="number">
            <input type="radio" id="no2" name="numbers" value="2" />
            <label for="no2">2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="number">
            <input type="radio" id="no3" name="numbers" value="3" />
            <label for="no3">3</label>
          </div>
          <div class="number">
            <input type="radio" id="no4" name="numbers" value="4" />
            <label for="no4">4</label>
          </div>
          <div class="number">
            <input type="radio" id="no5" name="numbers" value="5" />
            <label for="no5">5</label>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
```

```
.numbers-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  border: none;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
}

.number {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: hsl(217, 12%, 63%);
  background-color: hsl(213, 25%, 25%);
  border: none;
}

.number:hover {
  background-color: hsl(25, 97%, 53%);
  color: white;
}

.selected {
  background-color: hsl(217, 12%, 63%);
  color: white;
}
```

```
const ratingState = document.querySelector(".rating-state");
const thanksState = document.querySelector(".thanks-state");
const btnSubmit = document.querySelector(".btn-submit");
const numberSelect = document.querySelectorAll(".number");

for (let i = 0; i < numberSelect.length; i++)
  numberSelect[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("button clicked", numberSelect[i]);
    numberSelect[i].classList.add("selected");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't remove your `.selected` class for every radio button in the fieldset:

```js
const ratingState = document.querySelector(".rating-state");
const thanksState = document.querySelector(".thanks-state");
const btnSubmit = document.querySelector(".btn-submit");
const numberSelect = document.querySelectorAll(".number");

for (let i = 0; i < numberSelect.length; i++)
  numberSelect[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("button clicked", numberSelect[i]);
    if (numberSelect[i].classList.contains("selected")) numberSelect[i].classList.remove("selected");
    else {
      numberSelect.forEach((select) => select.classList.remove("selected"));
      numberSelect[i].classList.add("selected");
    }
  });
```

```css
.numbers-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  border: none;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
}

.number {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: hsl(217, 12%, 63%);
  background-color: hsl(213, 25%, 25%);
  border: none;
}

.number:hover {
  background-color: hsl(25, 97%, 53%);
  color: white;
}

.selected {
  background-color: hsl(217, 12%, 63%);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="numbers-container">
  <div class="number">
    <input type="radio" id="no1" name="numbers" value="1" />
    <label for="no1">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="number">
    <input type="radio" id="no2" name="numbers" value="2" />
    <label for="no2">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="number">
    <input type="radio" id="no3" name="numbers" value="3" />
    <label for="no3">3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="number">
    <input type="radio" id="no4" name="numbers" value="4" />
    <label for="no4">4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="number">
    <input type="radio" id="no5" name="numbers" value="5" />
    <label for="no5">5</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

On a side note, what you are trying to achieve is totally possible using just CSS:

```css
.numbers-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  border: none;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  /*  hide checkbox so that we only have to worry about label */
  display: none;
}


/*  select sibling label */

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: hsl(217, 12%, 63%);
  color: white;
}

label:hover {
  background-color: hsl(25, 97%, 53%);
  color: white;
}

label {
  /*  label size of div */
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*  center label text */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 3rem;
  /*  your other styling */
  background-color: hsl(213, 25%, 25%);
  color: hsl(217, 12%, 63%);
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="numbers-container">
  <input type="radio" id="no1" name="numbers" value="1" />
  <label for="no1">1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="no2" name="numbers" value="2" />
  <label for="no2">2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="no3" name="numbers" value="3" />
  <label for="no3">3</label>
  <input type="radio" id="no4" name="numbers" value="4" />
  <label for="no4">4</label>
  <input type="radio" id="no5" name="numbers" value="5" />
  <label for="no5">5</label>
</fieldset>
```